# compilation errors when trying to include boost/any.hpp from boost

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I am not sure what happened to my system, but now when I try to include boost/any.hpp in a program test.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

using g++ -o test test.cc, I get the following error:

```
In file included from test.cc:2:0:

/usr/include/boost/any.hpp: In function 'ValueType boost::any_cast(boost::any&)':

/usr/include/boost/any.hpp:278:52: error: 'if_' in namespace 'boost::mpl' does not name a template type

        typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::mpl::if_<
                                                   ^ /usr/include/boost/any.hpp:278:55: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token

        typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::mpl::if_<
                                                      ^ /usr/include/boost/any.hpp:284:28: error: 'ref_type' does not name a type

        return static_cast<ref_type>(*result);
```

Everything is fine when I remove the include to any.hpp.  I am using boost-1.56.0 and gcc-4.9.3.

Things were compiling fine a week ago, but I am not sure what I might have updated to cause this error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` to your command line

Comment: @RichardCritten Why would that solve the problem ? He is using `boost::any`, it should work w/o C++11 as well.

Comment: Are you able to work with any other boost constructs ?

Comment: Interesting, I can see boost::mpl::if_... being used in any.hpp but no apparent include related to it.  Try including <boost/mpl/if.hpp> above your any.hpp include.

Comment: @qexyn Adding an include to boost/mpl/if.hpp did the trick.  I didn't need to do this before, and I am not sure what changed.  The real reason I ran across this problem is I was having problems including boost/program_options.hpp, however, adding the include to if.hpp fixed everything.  Thanks.,